# Loop local storage object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I'm developing a shopping cart with local storage, I declare the local storage

`var cart = {};
 cart.products = [];
 localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));`

and add the products with AJAX from a data array with products details on a `onclick()` event

```
var product = {};
    product.id = msg.produto.id;
    product.name = msg.produto.nome;
    product.price = msg.produto.preco;
    product.image = msg.produto.name;

    addToCart(product);
```

the 'addToCart' function add the array to local storage object with `.push`

`var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
 cart.products.push(product);`

than, I need to do a `for` or `$.each` in javascript to get all the products details, one-by-one and add to my html.

I've tried this way:

```
localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));

var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("cart");

$.each(retrievedData , function (i, item) {

 alert(item.nome);
 alert(item.product.nome);

});
```

but don't work...

the `var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("cart");` object result lik

```
{"products":
    [
        {
        "id":"01",
        "name":"Product Name 01",
        "price":"Product Price 01",
        "image":"Product Imagem 01"
        },
        {
        "id":"02",
        "name":"Product Name 02",
        "price":"Product Price 02",
        "image":"Product Imagem 02"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("cart");
```

`retrievedData` will be a **string** containing JSON. You have to parse it first to get an object, using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Then you can follow techniques mentioned in [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196) to traverse the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Result from `localStorage` data you expect is an array which is the value of "products" property of returned object.

For this reason, I would try:

```
$.each(retrievedData.products , function (i, item) {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use utility like https://github.com/godban/local-storage-parser to simplify interaction with Local Storage